# UITableViewCell becomes unhighlighted on press down

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a subclass of a `UITableView` and a frustrating issue is occurring when a cell is selected and I press down on another cell, but don't release. As soon as I press down the selected cell becomes unhighlighted but the tableview delegate methods `didUnhighlightCell` and `willDeselectCell` don't get called until I release from the press. I do not want the cell to become*unhighlighted until I have selected a new cell on the release. I solved this by adding a long press gesture recognizer, but this a bulky solution and I want something cleaner.

Is there a simpler solution to this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a UITableView subclass, override touchesBegan:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    /* Improves the usability of a table view with selectable cells,
     * to prevent premature selection of a cell, during dragging.
     */
    if (!self.dragging && !self.tracking) {
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

This solves the problem of having the selected row unhighlighted during dragging. This is because `didHighlightRowAtIndexPath` and `didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath` don't get called until the new row is actually selected by the user.

If you want this kind of behavior in all your table views, you can tuck this away in a super class.